# WPF throw System.TypeLoadException

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

When I try to start WPF designer, it shows me following error message:
[image]

What is wrong? Visual Studio version is 2015.

Comment: What extra libraries you use?

Comment: I use infragistics and a project with name libraries. In the libraries, there is a class name Storage. Could it be, that the class Storage causes error?

Comment: I don't think so, when i was having same problem with VS 2015 and Telerik libraries, i fixed it by repairing (reinstalling) Telerik components.